# Batch program copy error

Tags: cmd, copy

I am making a batch program so I can backup my files automatically easily.
The Code is:

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\users\jamie\desktop\DOCUMENT\*.*" "C:\BACKUP\DOCUMENT\"
pause >nul
```

That isn't running.
I want it to copy all sub-directories, but it shows that:

```
0 file is copied.
```

What shall I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
xcopy "C:\users\jamie\desktop\DOCUMENT\*.*" "C:\BACKUP\DOCUMENT\"
```

to

```
xcopy "C:\users\jamie\desktop\DOCUMENT\*.*" "C:\BACKUP\DOCUMENT\" /E
```

`/E` here is to copy directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Same as `/S /E`.

P.S. you can use `/S` if you need copy directories and subdirectories except empty ones.

Check out [here](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) for more info.

Comment: It is very difficult to choose, as both answers are correct. However, your answer is clearer and suggest more possible solution, so I will choose yours. But wait! I can't accept an answer to early!

Comment: @Jamie Not a problem to select which, as long as it helps you. :)

Comment: That's alright. I wonder how you've got so much reputation? How long have you been in stacksoverflow? I'm just a few days.

Comment: @Jamie Actually active for the last month (mostly). You can make it too if you want by helping others.

Comment: Surprising. Being a secondary school student doesn't help me to get much time to write my program, even in form 1

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation.

```
xcopy /?
```

from the prompt will show you all of the switches available.

`/s` to copy subdirectories might be a good start.